# React Error: Invalid DOM property `tabindex` . Did you mean `tabIndex` Creating a modal with Bbootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, jsx

Sorry for my inglish:

I create  a component of a modal in React, compile good, but the console show this error:

Warning: Invalid DOM property tabindex. Did you mean tabIndex? in div (at ModalComponent.js:10) in div (at ModalComponent.js:5) in ModalComponent (at src/index.js:24) in div (at src/index.js:23) in ModalCreate (at src/index.js:32) in StrictMode (at src/index.js:31)

I' know that in react the atribute must be camalCase but bootstrap need this atribute to work. There is my code:

```
const ModalComponent = (props) => {
return (
    <div> {/* Tiene qe haber un solo elemento Padre */}
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target={props.obj.id}>
            {props.obj.btnCallModal}
        </button>

        <div className="modal fade" id={props.obj.id} tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div className="modal-content">
                    <div className="modal-header">
                        <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{props.obj.titulo}</h5>
                        <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-body">
                        {props.obj.body}
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">{props.obj.btnInModal}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

};

Comment: `tabIndex` should transpile to `tabindex` in DOM. Are you sure making it `tabIndex` didn't work? It may be other part of the code that may be at fault.

Answer (score 1):

In react, tabIndex corresponds to tabindex in html. Change it to tabIndex and the modal should work as expected.

Comment: Yes, I have to put tabIndex but, The problem finally was in the data-target, must have # before de ID. THX.